# Ionic 5 accept attribute for file type input is not working properly

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

After upgraded to ionic 5 I am not able to provide multiple file types in the `accept` attribute.
It worked in browser but it is not working in android devices.

```html
<input accept="image/*,video/*" name="file" type="file", id="file" [(ngModel)]="model.file">
```

The above code is not working properly it actually allows to pick the image file alone. Which means, it supports only the first `MIME type` in an accept attribute.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a good way to upload file. it is for browser based application. Ionic has a plugin for this I have mentioned URL below. you should go with this.

Android : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser

iOS : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-picker

Comment: I have used this but the problem is I need to choose only image and video not other files like pdf, doc etc...

Comment: If you see ion-input property https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input it has accept property. They have clearly mentioned `If the value of the type attribute is "file", then this attribute will indicate the types of files that the server accepts, otherwise it will be ignored.` I tried this ion-input too but still it is not working.

Comment: you can filter content for image only in plugin itself they have option for it. 

`let filter={ "mime": "image/*" }  // text/plain, image/png, image/jpeg, audio/wav etc
  this.fileChooser.open(filter) ... //Rest of the code`

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative that worked for me was to use the Camera plugin, this will allow you to pick an image from the media library, so it always be an image or video or take a picture from the camera

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera

Answer (score -1):

For Ionic I can recommend the Capacitor Plugin [file-picker](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-plugins/tree/main/packages/file-picker).